# How to send time to widget from an activity?

Tags: android, android-widget

I can make an app that shows the prayer time. I want that is also shows the time on the widget can any one tell me I can make widget and now the problem is how to send data on the widget I totally confused how to send time on the widget?/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this may be it will help you

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
        R.layout.widget);
Intent intent = new Intent();
if (intent.getAction().equals(
        Constants.ACTION_WIDGET_UPDATE_FROM_ACTIVITY)) {
    String widgetText = intent.getExtras().getString(
            Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_WIDGET_TEXT);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.word_text, widgetText);
} else {
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.word_text, showPrayer);
}
       `  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Write this code in your widget appwidgetprovider

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    if (intent.getAction().equals(
            Constants.ACTION_WIDGET_UPDATE_FROM_ACTIVITY)) {
        String widgetText = intent.getExtras().getString(
                Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_WIDGET_TEXT);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.word_text, widgetText);
    } else {
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.word_text, showPrayer);
    }
           `  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your activity....

```
   if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
                AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
                        .getInstance(context);
                RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context
                        .getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);


                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_time, ""
                        + YOURTIME);



                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
                Intent resultValue = new Intent();
                resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                        appWidgetId);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
            }
```

Comment: actually the problem is the app widget show the time when click on the time form app and disappread after some time.i want that shows time on the widget without clik on the time from app and it will shows the continuously.